# Do functions in the "os" module wait to be finished?

Tags: python, python-os

With:

```
import os
for file in files:
   os.remove(file)
```

Will it wait for every file to be removed like a synchronous function in each call to `os.remove()`, or will it iterate through while calling `os.remove()`?

Comment: It will wait for whatever the OS sees at completed. This does not necessarily mean that the file has been physically removed yet.

Comment: What do you consider "finished"? Especially file system operations may be journaled or buffered by the filesystem/OS before actually being applied.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi by finished I mean if the code does wait to delete the file to move on to the next line

Comment: @KlausD. is there any docs where I can see what means "completed" by the OS ?

Comment: I guess. But SO is not a document finding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the `os` module provides wrappers around [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) of the operating system. For example, on Linux the [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove)/[os.unlink](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unlink) functions correspond to the [`unlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man2/unlink.2.html) system call. These functions wait until the system call has finished.

Whether this means that the *high level* operation intended by the program has finished depends on the use-case.
For example, `unlink` merely removes the path pointing to the file content; if there are other paths for the same file (i.e. [hardlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)) or processes with a file handle on it, the file content remains. Only when all references are gone is the file content eligible for removal from the filesystem (similar to [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)). The filesystem itself may arbitrarily delay removal of the content, and distributed filesystems may have additional consistency and synchronisation constraints.

As a rule of thumb, if there are no special requirements then it is fine to consider the `os` call to be prompt and synchronous. If there are specific requirements, such as file content being completely destroyed, read up on the specific behaviour of the involved components.